# How do I use the verb(s) fallen lassen ("to drop") in the informal singular imperative?

Tags: imperative

My step-father and I have a long-standing joke in which I will tell him "don't drop the soap" (because he's in prison). I'm writing him a letter and I want to say this in German. I have two German textbooks, but they aren't very helpful in this case. I looked up what "to drop" is in German and I found that fallen lassen means what I want, but I don't know if I'm using it right. I wrote "Fall (du) nicht die Seife gelassen." Google translate and other websites keep giving me different results, so I have no idea which is correct.

Comment: Just curious: What is the relation between being in prison and dropping the soap?

Answer (score 9):

I'm assuming, you're having for example a phone call with your step-father at the end of which you might say: "Bye! And, oh, don't drop the soap!" In this case in my opinion the correct version would be:

> Lass nicht die Seife fallen!

As you can see  in the comments, there are a lot of ways to add or remove shades of meaning by changing the word order (emphasis) or adding flavouring particles. If you substantiate the particular context, you might get an answer even more precise. Otherwise this should do!

Comment: OK, thank you so much. I'm glad to see that I wasn't too far off.

Comment: Personally I'd prefer "Lass die Seife nicht fallen". Either way I'm not sure it works quite the same way in German.

Comment: You can add a "bloß", it is stylistically appropriate here and makes the expression more lively: "Lass *bloß* nicht die Seife fallen!"

Comment: All proposed solutions could benefit from an omission apostrophe: Lass -> Lass'

Comment: @guidot That would be wrong, because there's no omission. It's the imperative form of *lassen*, which is just *lass*!

Comment: @Em1: I disagree, see http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lassen, which at least shows lasse (which I would consider as less informal) as alternative to lass.

Comment: @guidot Fair enough, still no omission.

Comment: @Ingmar I edited my post slightly to make clear, what exact situation I was thinking of. Your version puts the emphasis on the soap, rather than on the act of dropping.

Comment: I'm afraid I still disagree, meaning that _nicht_ will have to come after the accusative object.

Comment: @Ingmar I disagree with you disagreeing :-) I bet the sentence *Lass unter keinen Umständen die Seife fallen!* would be OK for you? Then why would *Lass bloß nicht die Seife fallen!* or *Lass nicht die Seite fallen!* not be? *Lass nicht die Seife fallen* would emphasize that he shouldn't drop *the soap*, while *Lass die Seife nicht fallen* would tell him he can do about anything with the soap, but he *must not drop it*.

Comment: You can use "unter keinen Umständen" that way, but even there "Lass die Seife unter keinen Umständen fallen!" would be the better choice. Only when you propose a second, better alternative can you use "nicht" in that place: "Lass nicht die Seife fallen, sondern das Handtuch." Another test would be to substitute "die Seife" with "sie": Surely you wouldn't say "Lass nicht sie fallen"?

Comment: Where's the emphasis in the English sentence?